# Why does this HEVC HLS stream not play on browsers?

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, hevc

I have a HEVC HLS stream that does not play when I paste it e.g. in Safari. The video is encoded in HEVC and has a resolution of 4608x1728. The screen just stays black.

The URL is: https://cdn2.taggy.cam/videos/JFNi2a3JVxmUxWh8t6YkbzR5t9HyS94ZaQy81KVrbwJ2ztTp9f/hls/h265/video.m3u8

(or https://cdn2.taggy.cam/videos/JFNi2a3JVxmUxWh8t6YkbzR5t9HyS94ZaQy81KVrbwJ2ztTp9f/hls/h265/playlist.m3u8 for the master playlist)

VLC player does play it.

I tried several different players to get an error message, but the only thing I got was "MEDIA.VIDEO_ERROR (4,,CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: Video stream codec hevc doesn't match SourceBuffer codecs.)"

The video is initially created with FFMpeg by recording the RTSP stream of a webcam with

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://stream -tag:v hvc1 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename output-directory/video-%05d.m4s -c copy
```

Any ideas how to debug this would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Sebastian